# Referencing dict elements inside the dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to reference a dictionary element's value from another one while creating it?

Something like:

```
d = {key1: value1,
     key2: d[key1] + value2}
```

Comment: Are you trying to refer the value before it is assigned

Comment: No. The dictionary isn't defined until you finish defining it and you can't reference an object until you define it.

Comment: why not `key2: value1 + value2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the dictionary isn't defined at the time you try to refer it, this won't be possible. You could however break this down into multiple lines to refer to the dictionary in subsequent statements:

```
>>> d = {"key1": "value1"} 
>>> d["key2"] = d["key1"] + "value2"
>>> d
{'key2': 'value1value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: Well and is is possible to keep the referenced value as a reference, not as a value so, that when the value1 changes, value2 will reflect this change?

Comment: @PetrKrampl Nopes, not directly afaik. You could create a class, have a mutable structure somewhere, store references of the data within this structure, and finally compute the value every time you want it (because referenced values may change), but I don't think this is directly supported in any way.

Answer (score 0):

No,
You are defining `d`.

You will get an error `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you are trying to do it. At the moment you are trying to do `key2: d[0] + value2`, `d` is still being defined; in other words, it doesn't exist yet, and thus you can't access it.

On top of that, d[0] would be undefined as well, because 0 is not a key that exists in that dictionary.

I'm not sure if it would fit your needs but you could do it like this (assuming `key1`, `key2`, `value1` and `value2` have been defined previously):

```
d = {key1: value1}
d[key2] = d[key1] + value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead:

```
class TwoKeys(object):
  def __init__(self, val1, val2):
    self.val1 = val1
    self.val2 = val2
  @property
  def key1(self):
    return self.val1
  @property
  def key2(self):
    return self.val1 + self.val2

xmpl = TwoKeys(1,2)
print(xmpl.key1, xmpl.key2)
xmpl.val1 = 99
print(xmpl.key1, xmpl.key2)
```